# setbackgroundmessagehandler is not working in desktop register browser

Tags: reactjs, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

FCM send request successfully using the below API. but after api call success notification does not come in the desktop register browser.

I think setbackgroundmessagehandler is not fire.

```
"firebase": "^7.24.0"
```

API: POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

PayLoad:
`{"registration_ids":["eSETTfIfvcG_HNAAH7XJPc:APA91bGQKlqPs6EIKe5eFdFSDoLQuPJdG51GtUmtAPgoPqgA2x1_oHmf4k9UJyZEt36awBIlKbbmqPLMZEtl-VedHJqMHuNKPifqhHquadAhcYEyusqfGnJfll_ctVyDK81Gzk3hmXjL"],"collapse_key":"type_a","notification":{"title":"tilte","body":"hello message","imageUrl":"image url"},"data":{"uri":"insight://users/0OC0Lsbg7jeTW5P67F7JVE3Ynbv1","campaign":"server_test_push_premium:premium_push_aug_2023","push_notification_type":"FRIEND_REQUEST"}}`

Status Code:200

Project\public\firebase-messaging-sw.js

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.2/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/6.6.2/firebase-messaging.js');


try {
  if (firebase.messaging.isSupported()) {
    const messaging = firebase.messaging();
    messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler((payload) => {
      if (!Object.keys(payload).length) { return; }
      const notificationTitle = title;
      const notificationBody = body || '';
      const notificationIcon = icon || '';
      const notificationOptions = {
        body: notificationBody,  icon: notificationIcon,
        data: { url: click_action_url }, //the url which we gonna use later
        actions: [{ action: "open_url", title: "Read Now" }]
      };
      self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
    })
    self.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
      switch (event.action) {
        case 'open_url':
          clients.openWindow(event.notification.data.url); //which we got from above
          break;
      }
    }, false);
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.error("Firebase messaging service does not support in this browser, please use another browser, thanks", error);
}
```